# How to pass useState prop to another component after fetching data and modifying the data structure? Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm receiving undefined in the child component. If I console.log from the parent, I can see all the data but something happens when I pass the prop. Is this incorrect the way I do it ?

Here I set useState as an array that takes in 2 strings like a dictionary.

```
export interface superclassInfo {
  class: string;
  id: string;
}
const [classid, setClassid] = useState<superclassInfo[]>([]);
```

I fetch the data, modify the data structure and store it as state.

```
 let newJob = { class: job1, id: job2 };
 setClassid((value) => [...value, newJob]);
```

This is working perfectly, when I console.log, I see an array of objects with class:string, id:string
I pass prop to child component RankingSubclass with the state. (I believe this is where the undefined comes from, probably doing it wrong here).

```
useEffect(() => {
  <RankingSubclass classes={classid} />;
}, [classid]);
```

In RankingSubclass (child component), I import the interface and use a functional component but the console.log is undefined here

```
interface ComponentProps {
  classes: superclassInfo[];

const RankingSubclass: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({ classes }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ classes });
  });
}
```

Comment: ...putting `<RankingSubclass classes={classid} />` inside a `useEffect` like that doesn't actually do anything useful...

Comment: Naming things appropriately really helps. How is an array of objects a single id? You will confuse yourself before long

Comment: @JaredSmith I can put it inside a const and return it, but my child component still has an empty array

Comment: @AluanHaddad the array looks like this
classes:Array(8)
0: 
class: "test1"
id: "3qteafgdq3r"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: class
: 
"test2"
id
: 
"98uia4tegs4wt"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Comment: So you should use descriptive plural names because it's an array. That is what I thought. Your names are not plural and they suggest that rather than having an ID get the elements and the array are IDs.

Comment: Did you mean to `return <RankingSubclass classes={classid} />` from your component?

Comment: ...um yeah? Because you're giving the `useState` an empty array as the initial value? It will always be an empty array on *at least* the first render. The state update is asynchronous, even if the data fetch isn't (although it probably is).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding dependency array in your useEffect for your state in your child component. Check below code :-

```
const RankingSubclass: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({ classes }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ classes });
  },[classes]);
}
```

Rendering components directly inside useEffect is not a typical usage; instead, useEffect is primarily for side effects.